# Implement facebook android sdk in my android project

Tags: android

Now,I want to do an app to login and upload photo to facebook
I downloaded facebook android sdk file zar
I created a project SocialNetwork and I also import archive file sdk above.
It as follow:( i don't have permission to upload image directly)
http://nn2.upanh.com/b6.s26.d2/1e48fcdafe93b494c89afdb4897c1145_45504792.project1.png

But i don't know how use facebook sdk in LoginPage class because their package not as like.I want to call methods in facebook sdk to implement login and upload photo tomy app.How i must do?
When i add facebook sdk it displays error at this part in Facebook class

```
    @Override
    public void onServiceConnected(ComponentName className, IBinder service) {
        messageSender = new Messenger(service);
        refreshToken();
    }

    @Override
    public void onServiceDisconnected(ComponentName arg) {
        serviceListener.onError(new Error("Service disconnected"));
        // We returned an error so there's no point in
        // keeping the binding open.
        applicationsContext.unbindService(TokenRefreshServiceConnection.this);
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you take a look at [Facebook Tutorial](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/mobile/android/sso/)

**Read *Step1*** cartefully.it explains how to create facebook sdk project.

**Read Step2 and Step3** Carefully.it explains how to import that facebook library project
into current(your) project.

Once you are done you are free to call facebook API's.

Comment: I aslo read that tutorial but when i do step 1,it error..So I must add facebook sdk by archive file .

Comment: What error are you getting paste it here.it would help to identify problem